# Scrollbar shows up on Windows

Tags: windows, scrollbar, hidden, tidesdk

I have a problem with TideSDK on Windows 8.

I have in my tiapp.xml:

```xml
<chrome scrollbar="false">true</chrome>
```

But even with that, scrollbars show up, why?

I can hide them with jQuery or CSS using

```
overflow: hidden;
```

But I can't scroll anymore after that.

Can you help me please?

Sorry for my bad English, I'm French.

Comment: _It works under Linux Mint Cinamon latest version_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 6 year old answer is no longer a valid if you're dealing with Mobile...

--- OG Answer ---

Use the :hover selector on the scrollable pane...

```
.scrollpane {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.scrollpane:hover {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: It's still a little ugly but Im working on a custom webkit scrollbar UI to make it mimic OS X. If I get it to a point where I'm happy, I'll include it here.

Comment: This will not work on mobile devices, as mobile cursors cannot hover and activate the scrollable content.